# Is it possible to hash a whole result set in mysql?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to apply a hash function to an entire result set in mysql.

I know how to hash values in each row of a result set

e.g.  `SELECT md5('something')`

However say I have a query like

```
SELECT * FROM `some_table`
```

And the result set contains many rows is is it possible to hash the entire result set into one value?

I should be clear that I do not want a hash for each row. I want one hash of the whole result set.

i.e. one has of the entire set.

edited: to make requirement a bit clearer.

Comment: Do you want to hash every column, or hash all the data together?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

combine `CONCAT()` and `GROUP_CONCAT()`:

```
SELECT MD5(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(col1,col2,...))), 1 as g
  FROM some_table GROUP BY g;
```

Comment: Note that when applying this to an existing query you have to take out any aliases - CONCAT(YEAR(startDate) AS startYear) will throw an error, so just remove the " AS startYear" part.

Comment: This was not working for me as output of `GROUP_CONCAT` has a limited length. See my solution using array functions https://stackoverflow.com/a/77203421/586790

Answer (score 1):

You could concatenate all the columns together and use the result for `md5()`:

```
select md5(concat(col1, col2, . . . coln)) 
from some_table;
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to create a concatenated string of all the columns and then apply the hash.

```
SELECT MD5(CONCATE(COL1,COL2,COL3...COLn))
```

Comment: This will give me a hash per row, rather than a single hash of the entire set though? Sorry I've edited my post to make this requirement clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Having big data which needs to be hashed, using `GROUP_CONCAT` is dangerous, as the length of the output is restricted (by default to 1024). This could lead to same hashes even original result is different. `JSON_ARRAYAGG` will also aggregate the result but without restrictions.

Also using `CONCAT` is not the best practice as it returns `null` as soon as one value is `null`. To avoid this `CONCAT_WS` or `JSON_ARRAY` can be used.

So working with arrays is (for me) the better solution if the result has many rows and/or columns with possible `null` values.

```
select MD5(JSON_ARRAYAGG(JSON_ARRAY(col1, col2, col3, col5, ..., colX)))
  from some_table;
```