# Checksum in MySQL different

Tags: mysql, database, database-replication, checksum

Is there any reason why identical tables in MySQL 5.0 might have different checksums, and if so, is there any way to fix this?

I have two replicated databases that inexplicably have a different checksum.  The first time this happened it disappeared before I could properly replicate it and ask this question, and now it's happened for the second time in the same week.

When I manually check the tables, they are exactly the same, *i.e.* the checksums of every row correspond identically, the table structure is identical, and they're running on the same version of MySQL (`5.0.96-community-nt-log`), more over the DB replication (`Slave_IO_Running` and `Slave_SQL_Running`) reports normal operation.

How can the checksums possibly be different?

**Database A**:

```
MySQL [libertyintelligence]> select md5(concat(LS_MapAssetLinkId,LS_Map,LS_Asset,LS_X,LS_Y,LS_MinZoom,LS_MaxZoom,LS_ZOrder)) from ls_mapassetlink;
+----------------------------------+
| md5(...)                         |
+----------------------------------+
| c3c060c7c514ac3e410b50c0eb0f63f9 |
| a97a117c63f9a2472b96e517c303e42f |
| 946dacb76c8e2919d1ce791211da660c |
| 112a10fe77558beca686ec2c9281ce7d |
| 271b8de08f13252ff0e58ac20590c9ce |
| 837e88605f4a7b1e0f2a78d40bf8ce1f |
+----------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [libertyintelligence]> checksum table ls_mapassetlink;
+-------------------------------------+------------+
| Table                               | Checksum   |
+-------------------------------------+------------+
| libertyintelligence.ls_mapassetlink | 1670286008 |
+-------------------------------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

**Database B**:

```
MySQL [libertyintelligence]> select md5(concat(LS_MapAssetLinkId,LS_Map,LS_Asset,LS_X,LS_Y,LS_MinZoom,LS_MaxZoom,LS_ZOrder)) from ls_mapassetlink;

+----------------------------------+
| md5(...)                         |
+----------------------------------+
| c3c060c7c514ac3e410b50c0eb0f63f9 |
| a97a117c63f9a2472b96e517c303e42f |
| 946dacb76c8e2919d1ce791211da660c |
| 112a10fe77558beca686ec2c9281ce7d |
| 271b8de08f13252ff0e58ac20590c9ce |
| 837e88605f4a7b1e0f2a78d40bf8ce1f |
+----------------------------------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MySQL [libertyintelligence]> checksum table ls_mapassetlink;
+-------------------------------------+-----------+
| Table                               | Checksum  |
+-------------------------------------+-----------+
| libertyintelligence.ls_mapassetlink | 123437249 |
+-------------------------------------+-----------+
```

Or specifically, one DB shows the table checksum as **1670286008** while the other as **123437249**, when the data shows me that the tables are identical.

Both my co-workers and I have checked this independently (independently connected to the DB, independently checked, *etc.*), and are both stumped.  The only reason I can find that checksums might be different are if I was using different DB versions, but these are the same version too.

**Table schema**
The schema is identical on both systems:

```
CREATE TABLE `ls_mapassetlink` (
  `LS_MapAssetLinkId` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `LS_Map` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `LS_Asset` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `LS_X` double NOT NULL,
  `LS_Y` double NOT NULL,
  `LS_MinZoom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LS_MaxZoom` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `LS_ZOrder` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`LS_MapAssetLinkId`),
  KEY `INDEX_MapAssetLink_Map` (`LS_Map`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=16 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

**Update**: [Found very similar question on DBA.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/71746/112523)

Comment: I wonder what a direct compare of bith files would show, i think they must be somehow differet like the documentation says. Did you check if a backup from the original server gives you also a different checksum, when you restore it on server 2?

Comment: You could try using [pt-table-checksum](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/LATEST/pt-table-checksum.html), which is a reliable row-by-row comparison. But I can't guarantee it works on MySQL 5.0.

Comment: @BillKarwin I'm new to pt-table-checksum actually, I gave it a try, and you're right, MySQL 5.0 is simply too old.

Comment: I'm starting to think that I was simply assuming that the checksum should be the same given the same data, where in reality maybe the rows are ordered differently, or space is allocated differently, or something, that's causing a difference.

When I run `select MD%(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(...))) from ls_mapassetlink ORDER BY LS_MapAssetLinkId;`, I get the same result on both tables. (got `GROUP_CONCAT` from https://stackoverflow.com/a/26487684/1861346)

Comment: Caution about using GROUP_CONCAT(): "The result is truncated to the maximum length that is given by the group_concat_max_len system variable, which has a default value of 1024." So no wonder it's giving the same checksum result — it's only examining a fraction of your data! See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Ack, glad you mentioned that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found to solve this problem was to implement my "checksum". Something like

```
select md5(GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT_WS(column1,column2))) from table
```

This

1. Concatenate all column values
2. Concatenate all rows
3. Calculate MD5 of the result string

I would expect computation to take some time table has millions of rows.